# How to find the call stack when there is just a corrupt stack corefile?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, coredump

a coredump file with corrupt stack, no any usefull info. How can I find the call stack?
the stack shows:

```
#0  0x04229c7a in ?? ()
#1  0x00921fa7 in ?? ()
#2  0xbfc17e04 in ?? ()
```

Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

and the address of eip shows "cannot access memory".

Comment: Do you have any other kind of log-files that can help you? It might help in giving you a clue about the approximate location of the problem. Or go all the way, with function tracing, so you can see *exaclty* what happens.

Comment: can not find any usefull info from log!

Comment: If you are code doesnot contain any dynamic libraries, you can probably try mapping this addresses to functions via the map file.

Comment: If it's reproducible this then use a debugger and don't try using the core file.  If it isn't then the first thing to realize is that almost every function creates a stack frame on entry.  This creates a chain of pointers which constantly point higher up on the stack.  Play around with the debugger and try to understand what your stack frame looks like normally.  Figure out how to identify the stack frame elements and the return instruction pointer on the stack then go back to your core file and find the stack frame.  The higher parts of the stack will most likely still be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying the call stack requires correct instruction pointer (eip), stack pointer (esp) and valid stack contents.

From your output it looks like the stack had been corrupted and the previous function returned to some random address (eip=0x04229c7a).

So, you are out of luck.

Try running your program under valgrind.

Comment: Try running your app under valgrind.